# Can I define these types in Java or Scala?

Tags: java, scala, types

This is a very basic question about *types* in programming languages. Now I am using the same type `Integer` for very different computations: e.g. for calculating both factorial and fibonacci numbers.

However `Integer` seems to me a very broad type for those computations. What if I define different more *specific* types `Factorial` or `Fibonacci[Integer]` instead ?

Do such types make sense ? Can I define them in Java or Scala ?

Comment: Does what make sense?

Comment: I mean: _Do such types make sense ?_ /editing the question/

Comment: Of course you can define custom types in either language.  So it's not completely clear what you're asking.

Comment: I do not know how to define `Factorial` or `Fibonacci<Integer>` in Java, for example.

Comment: What would an instance of `Fibonacci[Int]` be?

Comment: n-th Fibonacci number of course.

Comment: `class Factorial { /* Implementation goes here */ }`...

Comment: Are you assuming a type-level representation of the integers, then?

Comment: I do not know. Is it really necessary for defining `Fibonacci[Int]` ?

Comment: Well ... I probably should delete this question and think it over again. I am just thinking about using more narrow _specific_ types for _specific_ computations (like calculating Fibonacci numbers) instead of using broad types like Integer that look too vague for this purpose.

Comment: @Michael it more or less makes sense: the recent addiction to scala [(value types)](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) was done to introduce such types (classes) without any penalty: say you are writing some physics engine and you don't want to ever mess grams with meters. In your particular case I don't see how such indistinction might lead to the error, but this doesn't mean it is pointless [at least in general]. By the way, similar thing exists in some other languages, [e.g. F#](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Units_of_Measure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but if you have a type-level representation of the natural numbers (I'll use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/)'s in this answer), you can write a meaningful `Fibonacci` type class like this, for example:

```
import shapeless._, Nat._

trait Factorial[N <: Nat] { type Value <: Nat }

implicit object fact0 extends Factorial[_0] { type Value = _0 }
implicit object fact1 extends Factorial[_1] { type Value = _1 }

implicit def factN[N <: Nat, X <: Nat, Y <: Nat, Z <: Nat](implicit
  nf: Factorial[N]       { type Value = X },
  sf: Factorial[Succ[N]] { type Value = Y },
  sum: ops.nat.Sum.Aux[X, Y, Z]
) = new Factorial[Succ[Succ[N]]] { type Value = Z }
```

Then I can ask the type system to prove for example that the seventh Fibonacci number is thirteen (because it is):

```
scala> implicitly[Factorial[_7] { type Value = _13 }]
res1: Factorial[shapeless.Nat._7]{type Value = shapeless.Nat._13} = $anon$1@795adafd
```

But not that the seventh Fibonacci number is twelve:

```
scala> implicitly[Factorial[_7] { type Value = _12 }]
<console>:23: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Factorial[shapeless.Nat._7]{type Value = shapeless.Nat._12}
              implicitly[Factorial[_7] { type Value = _12 }]
                        ^
```

This approach uses the [Church encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) of the natural numbers. You could also use singleton types with macros in Scala 2.10—see for example [my blog post here](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/28/singleton-types-for-literals-in-scala/) for some discussion of singleton types in Scala.

Comment: Great ! Thanks. Now I have something to think it over !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it would not quite make sense to define those as types. They should probably be functions or methods. Like this

```
public class MathUtils {
    public static int factorialOf(int n) {
      ...
    }
}
```

But as a strictly legal matter, you can of course create classes called `Factorial` and `Fibonacci` that have public methods that presumably perform those operations like the one above.